# JAVA process two stream into one single map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two streams

```java
Stream<Key> keys;
Stream<Value> values;
```

I want combine them into a single `Map`

```java
Map<Key, Value> result = someMagicMethod(keys, values);
```

Is there any elegant way to do that?

I know there is a method called [Stream.concat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)), but it's not for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Guava Streams.zip for streams without random access

If Guava is available at runtime, then the following can help:

```java
        List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("One", "Two");
        List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
        Map<String, Integer> zipped = Streams.zip(keys.stream(), values.stream(), SimpleEntry::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
        System.out.println(zipped);
```

Comment: Great answer, only one problem: even with latest version(`30.1-jre`) of guava, this api is marked with `@Beta`

Comment: @user1686407, True, the `Streams` is marked as `@Beta` for a very long time. To handle the possibility of change/removal in this api, it can be abstracted in an Util class. It might be an overhead in some applications and please decide if it's suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can first collect both streams to a `List`.

```
List<Key> keyList = keys.collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Value> valueList = values.collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Key, Value> map = IntStream.range(0, keyList.size())
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyList::get, valueList::get));
System.out.println(map);
```